# Execute line in screen area when socket function from another component if called. -React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an external socket function

```
export default class SocketInstance
{
   static getSocketInstance()
   {
       ...
   }
   
   ...

   listen(aState)
   {
      ...
      return !aState
   }
}
```

Then in my screen area

import SocketInstance from '.../...';

```
export default class screenArea extends Component
{  
   screenArea()
   {
       this.state={
         theState: false
       }
   }   

   render()
   {
       return(....)
   }

   componentDidMount()
   {
       this.socket = SocketInstance.getSocketInstance();
       const getReturningState = this.socket.listen(this.state.theState)
       console.warn(getReturningState)  //Only print initially but not after the listen is triggered
   }
}
```

For simplicity, is there a way to get the state printed in the screenArea after the get listen is triggered? Again for simplicity, I am using print but I need to do something else in the screenArea.